# Get tags on user photos facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to get the number of people a user is tagging in each of his photos.

For this I first tried to get all photos via

```
me?fields=albums{photos{id}}
```

and then on each of them get the tags with

```
{photo-id}/tags
```

in a for loop.

This works but is extremely slow due to all the connections that get established while running through the for loop.

Is there a better way to do it or to somehow combine both things in one query?

I was thinking sth like

```
me?fields=albums{photos{id{tags}}}
```

but unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request

```
GET /me?fields=albums{photos{id,tags}}
```

works for me...